# How do I prevent Visual Studio Code from auto-generating code for me?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am a CS student and am starting to work on Leetcode problems. I am trying to use VSCode as my IDE for my solutions but have run into an issue as the IDE is predicting what code I am going to write based on the function names, probably due to the fact that it has seen thousands of similar functions. Does anyone know how to stop this? I have attached a picture below to show what I mean if I explained it poorly.

[image]

I have looked up solutions to this issue but haven't found anything helpful, it started after I downloaded the Java package for the app and I think it has something to do with IntelliSense or IntelliCode. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that's [Github Copilot](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot). Just uninstall/disable that extension. Then exit and restart Visual Studio Code.

Details on managing VSCode extensions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace

Comment: That worked thank you so much, I thought I had tried that, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is provided by **Github Copilot**. If you don't want to uninstall or disable the extension. Use the setting below to turn this feature off.

```
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think it has something to do with IntelliSense or IntelliCode

Yes, if you have [the `VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) installed, or any other extension that provides inline suggestions using [the `InlineCompletion` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InlineCompletionItemProvider) (such as GitHub Copilot, TabNine, etc.), you'll see inline suggestions like what you're seeing now. If you don't want those suggestions, disable the extension that's providing them. Or you can set the `editor.inlineSuggest.enabled` setting to `false`, which makes them not show up automatically as you're typing (you can still trigger them to show up manually by using the `Trigger Inline Suggestion` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)). If you have many extensions installed and want to figure out which one is contributing the inline suggestions, do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).