How do I disable code suggestions for Visual Studio Code, Windows
I want to disable these code suggestions, I think it is IntelliSense, from my VS Code:

I tried changing the settings.json, but it isn't working.
What I added is as follows:
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
    "editor.hover.enabled": false,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,


that looks like copilot, not intellisense

which extensions do you have installed ? (and versions)

dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77715724/11107541 probably

this may be caused by some extensions. For example, GitHub Copilot. What extensions do you install? You can find the installed extension and select Disable or Uninstall. Then restart vscode again and see if the problem is resolved.

Hey, thanks, it works now :)
