How do I disable partial line code suggestions in Visual Studio Code?
I have the C# and C# Dev Kit extensions installed in Visual Studio Code. Sometimes the editor will suggest code to complete a line or portion of a line, such as this example in the orange box:

How do I disable this functionality in Visual Studio Code?

In general this just looks like intelllisense ... is that what you want to turn off? Also fwiw  kSpeedPrefix is your variable you just declared. Why are you calling it garbage?

@topsail The greyed text in orange box. It is garbage because it is invalid C# that can't pass compilation: kSpeedPrefix is String; it is suggesting (String, int) for an overload prototype of (int). (For another simple example, it may suggest <str>.Length())

That's how intellisense works. It doesn't give you the correct choice, it gives you choices. You can just type normally if you don't want any of those choices. I don't use copilot so I don't know offhand to tell if that is copilot suggestions or just intellisense. First make sure you are not using copilot if you don't want copilot. Its very rare that users of an IDE such as VSCode don't want intellisense but I presume that can be disabled too.

Resources: make sure copilot is not the culprit: how-do-i-enabledisable-copilot Disable intellisense: how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown Intellisense in VSCode: VSCode-Intellisense

What did you make kSpeedPrefix equal to?

@topsail I said that kSpeedPrefix is String. (No copilot-like extension is installed)

dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77715724/11107541

You can disable inline suggestions from IntelliCode:

Go to File > Preferences > Settings.
Search for IntelliCode and find the settings labeled Editor: Inline Suggestions.
Uncheck Editor:Inline Suggestions to disable it.

Some C# extensions, like the C# Dev Kit, might also have settings for IntelliSense or AI-based suggestions

Go to Settings and search for C# Dev Kit or just C#.
Look for any settings that control IntelliSense or AI-based suggestions, and adjust them as needed.

